# display Flexible Fields from options

Tags: custom-field, advanced-custom-fields

I am having a problem displaying the content using ACF and flexible fields. I made a custom option page and I want to call the fields from the options page but everything is coming back blank when I try to get the values from the actual field.

This is my Code.

```
if( have_rows('season_title', 'option') ):

    while ( have_rows('season_title', 'option') ) : the_row();

        if( get_row_layout() == 'seasonal_title' ):

           print_r(the_sub_field('s_title'));

        endif;

    endwhile;

else :

    // no layouts found

endif;
```

This is the configuration on my field

[image]

Any ideas what im doing wrong?

Comment: Could you show your code for setting up the options page?

Comment: @Nath it's in the post

Comment: Your row layout might need option: `if( get_row_layout() == 'seasonal_title' ):`.

Answer (score 0):

According to ACF Docs on [Get values from an options page](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get-values-from-an-options-page/).

You should use **'option' not 'options'** as the second parameter to the `have_rows()` function.

```
<?php if( have_rows('repeater', 'option') ): ?>

    <ul>

    <?php while( have_rows('repeater', 'option') ): the_row(); ?>

        <li><?php the_sub_field('title'); ?></li>

    <?php endwhile; ?>

    </ul>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Option is in my code, however that still does not solve the problem I am having